# Can anyone spot the syntax error in this piece of PHP code

Tags: php, pdo

I've re-read it several times, and I still don't see where I made the mistake. Here is the error message :

[image]

and here is the related piece of code :

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text (especially ones that are unreadably small).  Post the text itself.

Comment: The explain is in the error message: MySQL does not understand what is `:id` and this is because it shouldn't be there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not readable, thus useless to be googled by future readers anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `$db->query()` when you should be calling `$db->prepare()`